# sensor_msgs/Imu Frame of reference?

Tags: imu, sensor-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the frame of reference for sensor_msgs/Imu?

It seems vague.

If the gyro rotate in counter clockwise direction around +Z direction is angular_velocity.z positive or negative?

If the robot is stationary then would  linear_acceleration.z be +9.8 m/s^2 or -9.8 m/s^2 ?

If the robot moves from zero velocity to 1m/s in the X direction would linear_acceleration.x be positive or negative?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257304/sensor_msgs/imu-frame-of-reference?/) by [Archhaskeller](https://answers.ros.org/users/29156/archhaskeller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2017-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see if #q255867 and the linked REP / discussions answer some of your questions.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0